# Conditional Variance Formulae

Tags: variance, continuous-data

Would I be correct in stating that the conditional variance of $Y$ given
that $X = x$ of a continuous distribution is as follows:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[y- \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} y f_{Y|X} (y|x) dy\right)\right]^2 f_{Y|X} (y|x) dy$$

I was just running through some true or false questions and the question asked whether the following was the conditional variance of $Y$ given that $X = x$:

$$\int_{-\infty} ^{+\infty} \left[y- \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} y f_{Y} (z) dz\right)\right]^2 f_{Y|X} (y|x) dy$$

I did not understand the presence of the z, and I have found out the answer is true. I assume I must be missing something, any guidance on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must be missing something because the second formula is false. Note that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_Y(z)dz = y\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(z)dz = y$$ and so the quantity inside the square brackets is $y-y=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first formula is correct by definition of conditional variance :

$$E[(Y-\mu_{Y|x})^2|x]=\int ^{+\infty}_{-\infty} [y- (\int ^{+\infty}_{-\infty} y f_{y|x} (y|x) dy)]^2 f_{y|x} (y|x) dy$$

where $$\int ^{+\infty}_{-\infty} y f_{y|x} (y|x) dy=\mu_{Y|x}$$ 
Your second formula  is not correct and **Dilip's** comment is correct. so your book's answer might not be correct.

Comment: Ok, I miss the $dz$ as $dy$. I think $\int ^{+\infty}_{-\infty} y f_{y|x} (y|x) dy=\mu_{Y|x}$

Comment: You are right, If I answer this question, my answer probably will be "not true" which should be the correct answer. It is not because I understand the problem well, but because my misunderstand the question.